# iOS app: OpenGL Views within Storyboard-based Application

Tags: ios, uiview, opengl-es-2.0, xcode-storyboard, eaglview

I have been working on an iOS, OpenGL-based app for the past few months. During this time, I have created both the main UIWindow and a single UIView in code, as opposed to using a storyboard.  An important item to note is that I create an instance of EAGLView (used in many Apple examples), which inherits from UIView.

The code base I am working with is quite extensive, and among other things, it uses a separate rendering thread.  I'll come back to this point near the end of this post.

With this in mind, I am now at the point that I want to add native UI support.  To do this, I am using a storyboard (for the first time).  My current setup consists of a main/root view with two buttons.  Each button uses a modal segue to place a new view on the screen.

To reuse as much code as possible, I have specified that the views I segue to are of type EAGLView (as opposed to UIView).  The only change I've had to make is that instead of initializing with "initWithFrame", I now initialize with "initWithCoder".

Other than moving to a storyboard, nothing else in the code base has changed.  However, when I segue to an EAGLView, nothing renders -- all I see is white.  I am hesitant to use GLKit because it duplicates much of the functionality I have already written (I had everything rendering just fine prior to using a storyboard).  In addition, GLKit provides a callback for rendering, whereas, I have a separate render thread.

My scenario sounds a lot like this post:

[OpenGL iOS view does not paint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7265594/opengl-ios-view-does-not-paint)

I have GL error checks for every call (or for every group of calls), and no errors are being reported.  What's even stranger is that when I capture an OpenGL ES frame for debugging (in Xcode), the debugger actually shows the content I expect to see.

Any ideas here?  I am stumped.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following:

1. Verify that you stop rendering in the view that you're segueing from (stopping times etc.) - this view is still alive since you only pushed a new EAGLView on top of it.
2. Use [XCode's OpenGL ES Frame capture](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Articles/xcode_4_2.html) to debug your OpenGL state in the new view. Verify that you're not missing binding to textures or other objects.
3. If the above doesn't work - write the simplest rendering possible (simple quad, for example) and debug that code.